# How can I print a list with a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, printing

I'm trying to print a list of my favorite games in addition to some text.

Code:

```
favGames = ["The Division", "WoW", "Legend of Zelda", "Super Smash Bros."]

print("Here are some of my favorite games! " + favGames)
```

Expectation:
I expected to simply get a print line of:

```
Here are some of my favorite games! The Division, WoW, Legend of Zelda, Super Smash Bros.
```

I'm receiving the following error message:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.join`, and join it by a command and a space:

```
print("Here are some of my favorite games! " + ', '.join(favGames))
```

Output:

```
Here are some of my favorite games! The Division, WoW, Legend of Zelda, Super Smash Bros.
```

Comment: Thanks!! that definitely worked on my end; I'll look into the join statement. Just starting out with coding honestly

Comment: Ebeeze if you feel that @U10-Forward answered your question then you should accept his answer.

Comment: @KingMak - not sure what you're referring to; I don't see such an option on this page.

Comment: @Ebeeze have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)